# How Can I Compare a Separate Derived Class Pointer to a Separate Base Class Pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

If I have two classes such as:

```
    class Base : boost::noncopyable {
    using ptr_type = std::shared_ptr<Base>;
    }

    class DerivedOne : public Base{    
    using ptr_type = std::shared_ptr<DerivedOne>;
    }

    class DerivedTwo : public SomeOtherBase{
    using ptr_type = std::shared_ptr<DerivedTwo>;
    }
```

If I want to have a usage as specified below, how could I compare a `DerivedOne::ptr_type` or a `DerivedTwo::ptr_type` to a `Base::ptr_type`? Is there a way to do this so that it's like comparing a `DerivedOne` or a `DerivedTwo` to a `Base`? My preferred usage is:

`if(DerivedOne::ptr_type == Base::ptr_type`) should return true.

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't "compare" type aliases. I'm not saying it's a good idea (it usually isn't) but you can perhaps do something with the [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator.

Comment: Well, I just wrapped both of the pointers in typeid() and it seems to give an expected result. Why is this not a good idea?

Comment: Because it breaks LSP.